# can we get thread id of thread in strace output of the multithreaded process?

Tags: linux, multithreading

just wondering if strace can give you a thread id of the thread who called the system call in case of multithreaded application. If it can be doable can please someone help me with the strace option i need to use for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`strace -f` does that on linux. It prints `pid` but it's really a thread id - though if the straced program also forks and e.g. executes external commands, those will show up as well.

Comment: too bad that it still shows up in the output as "[pid 29612]" when in reality it means "[tid 29612]" ...